# NodeJS email proxy

Tags: javascript, email, node.js

I am trying to proxy emails via NodeJS in order to do very custom processing on outgoing emails on our test server.

This is what I have:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer({allowHalfOpen: true}, function(socket) {
    console.log('New connection established.');
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Connection closing.');
    });

    socket.resume();
});

server.listen(25);
```

It does not yet process the emails, because it simply doesn't even work. I get the connection established message in console every time I send an email, but the data event never gets fired. I'm not sure if it's that the data already came before I bound the event listener, or whether I'm supposed to talk to the client first (`HELO`?).

I'm trying to access the email contents, basically.

Comment: Fyi, what you are trying to do is far away from trivial. You need to handle things such as STARTTLS, command pipelining etc. too. If your can make your mailserver invoke your script for an incoming email things would be **much** easier.